# how to detect unexpected url change python webdriver selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am automating a browser process but same credentials are used by all the persons(only one user can access the portal at a time), so whenever somebody else login-in, the current user is automatically  kicked out with url change to "http://172.17.3.248:8889/ameyoreports/?acpMode=false#loggedOut".

Is there any way to constantly check for url change while my automatation script is running along and when logout is detected end the script.

I am using python selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

In Java we can take help from EventLister https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html  for example if you implement it

```
public class Test2 implements WebDriverEventListener{

@Override
public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver driver) {
    if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equals("http://172.17.3.248:8889/ameyoreports/?acpMode=false#loggedOut")==true) {
        //do want you want.
    }
}
```

we have to use the same like below to cross check url before doing any action (as per above example, cross check url before finding element)

```
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);

    EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();
    eventDriver.register(handler);
    eventDriver.get("url");
```

in Java it helps http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/ for python http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.abstract_event_listener

Answer (score 0):

hey there is current_url attribute associated with the selenium webdriver object, you will be able to fetch the changed url using webdriver.current_url.

Keep a check for that and you can break your script whenever you want.

You can test it with the following code

```
#using chrome webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


browser = Options()
instance = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_path, options=browser)
instance.get(url)
instance.current_url <<<<<<< this will give the current url opened in browser

# manually enter another url in the browser then again check
instance.current_url
```